# PBKDF2 not the same

Tags: command-line, hashsum

I am trying to calculate a PBKDF2 hash, but am getting inconsistent results.

```
Message: Hello
Salt: 60C100D05C610E8B94A854DFC0789885
Iterations: 1
Key length: 16

Expected hash: 584519EF3E56714E301A4D85F972B6B4
```

- `nettle-pbkdf2` gives `a951d3cd9014e0c0 527000727c1e928a`
- `https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/PBKDF2z` and `CryptoJS` gives `584519EF3E56714E301A4D85F972B6B4`

**How can I use `nettle-pbkdf2` or any other CLI program to generate the expected hash `584519EF3E56714E301A4D85F972B6B4`?**

Reproduction steps below:

`nettle-pbkdf2`

```
$ printf "Hello" | nettle-pbkdf2 --iterations=1 --length=16 --hex-salt 60C100D05C610E8B94A854DFC0789885
> a951d3cd9014e0c0 527000727c1e928a
```

`https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/PBKDF2z`

```
Message: Hello
Salt: 60C100D05C610E8B94A854DFC0789885
Iterations: 1
Key length: 16

Hash: 584519EF3E56714E301A4D85F972B6B4
```

`CryptoJS`

```
<script>
/*
CryptoJS v3.1.2
code.google.com/p/crypto-js
(c) 2009-2013 by Jeff Mott. All rights reserved.
code.google.com/p/crypto-js/wiki/License
*/
var CryptoJS=CryptoJS||function(g,j){var e={},d=e.lib={},m=function(){},n=d.Base={extend:function(a){m.prototype=this;var c=new m;a&&c.mixIn(a);c.hasOwnProperty("init")||(c.init=function(){c.$super.init.apply(this,arguments)});c.init.prototype=c;c.$super=this;return c},create:function(){var a=this.extend();a.init.apply(a,arguments);return a},init:function(){},mixIn:function(a){for(var c in a)a.hasOwnProperty(c)&&(this[c]=a[c]);a.hasOwnProperty("toString")&&(this.toString=a.toString)},clone:function(){return this.init.prototype.extend(this)}},
q=d.WordArray=n.extend({init:function(a,c){a=this.words=a||[];this.sigBytes=c!=j?c:4*a.length},toString:function(a){return(a||l).stringify(this)},concat:function(a){var c=this.words,p=a.words,f=this.sigBytes;a=a.sigBytes;this.clamp();if(f%4)for(var b=0;b<a;b++)c[f+b>>>2]|=(p[b>>>2]>>>24-8*(b%4)&255)<<24-8*((f+b)%4);else if(65535<p.length)for(b=0;b<a;b+=4)c[f+b>>>2]=p[b>>>2];else c.push.apply(c,p);this.sigBytes+=a;return this},clamp:function(){var a=this.words,c=this.sigBytes;a[c>>>2]&=4294967295<<
32-8*(c%4);a.length=g.ceil(c/4)},clone:function(){var a=n.clone.call(this);a.words=this.words.slice(0);return a},random:function(a){for(var c=[],b=0;b<a;b+=4)c.push(4294967296*g.random()|0);return new q.init(c,a)}}),b=e.enc={},l=b.Hex={stringify:function(a){var c=a.words;a=a.sigBytes;for(var b=[],f=0;f<a;f++){var d=c[f>>>2]>>>24-8*(f%4)&255;b.push((d>>>4).toString(16));b.push((d&15).toString(16))}return b.join("")},parse:function(a){for(var c=a.length,b=[],f=0;f<c;f+=2)b[f>>>3]|=parseInt(a.substr(f,
2),16)<<24-4*(f%8);return new q.init(b,c/2)}},k=b.Latin1={stringify:function(a){var c=a.words;a=a.sigBytes;for(var b=[],f=0;f<a;f++)b.push(String.fromCharCode(c[f>>>2]>>>24-8*(f%4)&255));return b.join("")},parse:function(a){for(var c=a.length,b=[],f=0;f<c;f++)b[f>>>2]|=(a.charCodeAt(f)&255)<<24-8*(f%4);return new q.init(b,c)}},h=b.Utf8={stringify:function(a){try{return decodeURIComponent(escape(k.stringify(a)))}catch(b){throw Error("Malformed UTF-8 data");}},parse:function(a){return k.parse(unescape(encodeURIComponent(a)))}},
u=d.BufferedBlockAlgorithm=n.extend({reset:function(){this._data=new q.init;this._nDataBytes=0},_append:function(a){"string"==typeof a&&(a=h.parse(a));this._data.concat(a);this._nDataBytes+=a.sigBytes},_process:function(a){var b=this._data,d=b.words,f=b.sigBytes,l=this.blockSize,e=f/(4*l),e=a?g.ceil(e):g.max((e|0)-this._minBufferSize,0);a=e*l;f=g.min(4*a,f);if(a){for(var h=0;h<a;h+=l)this._doProcessBlock(d,h);h=d.splice(0,a);b.sigBytes-=f}return new q.init(h,f)},clone:function(){var a=n.clone.call(this);
a._data=this._data.clone();return a},_minBufferSize:0});d.Hasher=u.extend({cfg:n.extend(),init:function(a){this.cfg=this.cfg.extend(a);this.reset()},reset:function(){u.reset.call(this);this._doReset()},update:function(a){this._append(a);this._process();return this},finalize:function(a){a&&this._append(a);return this._doFinalize()},blockSize:16,_createHelper:function(a){return function(b,d){return(new a.init(d)).finalize(b)}},_createHmacHelper:function(a){return function(b,d){return(new w.HMAC.init(a,
d)).finalize(b)}}});var w=e.algo={};return e}(Math);
(function(){var g=CryptoJS,j=g.lib,e=j.WordArray,d=j.Hasher,m=[],j=g.algo.SHA1=d.extend({_doReset:function(){this._hash=new e.init([1732584193,4023233417,2562383102,271733878,3285377520])},_doProcessBlock:function(d,e){for(var b=this._hash.words,l=b[0],k=b[1],h=b[2],g=b[3],j=b[4],a=0;80>a;a++){if(16>a)m[a]=d[e+a]|0;else{var c=m[a-3]^m[a-8]^m[a-14]^m[a-16];m[a]=c<<1|c>>>31}c=(l<<5|l>>>27)+j+m[a];c=20>a?c+((k&h|~k&g)+1518500249):40>a?c+((k^h^g)+1859775393):60>a?c+((k&h|k&g|h&g)-1894007588):c+((k^h^
g)-899497514);j=g;g=h;h=k<<30|k>>>2;k=l;l=c}b[0]=b[0]+l|0;b[1]=b[1]+k|0;b[2]=b[2]+h|0;b[3]=b[3]+g|0;b[4]=b[4]+j|0},_doFinalize:function(){var d=this._data,e=d.words,b=8*this._nDataBytes,l=8*d.sigBytes;e[l>>>5]|=128<<24-l%32;e[(l+64>>>9<<4)+14]=Math.floor(b/4294967296);e[(l+64>>>9<<4)+15]=b;d.sigBytes=4*e.length;this._process();return this._hash},clone:function(){var e=d.clone.call(this);e._hash=this._hash.clone();return e}});g.SHA1=d._createHelper(j);g.HmacSHA1=d._createHmacHelper(j)})();
(function(){var g=CryptoJS,j=g.enc.Utf8;g.algo.HMAC=g.lib.Base.extend({init:function(e,d){e=this._hasher=new e.init;"string"==typeof d&&(d=j.parse(d));var g=e.blockSize,n=4*g;d.sigBytes>n&&(d=e.finalize(d));d.clamp();for(var q=this._oKey=d.clone(),b=this._iKey=d.clone(),l=q.words,k=b.words,h=0;h<g;h++)l[h]^=1549556828,k[h]^=909522486;q.sigBytes=b.sigBytes=n;this.reset()},reset:function(){var e=this._hasher;e.reset();e.update(this._iKey)},update:function(e){this._hasher.update(e);return this},finalize:function(e){var d=
this._hasher;e=d.finalize(e);d.reset();return d.finalize(this._oKey.clone().concat(e))}})})();
(function(){var g=CryptoJS,j=g.lib,e=j.Base,d=j.WordArray,j=g.algo,m=j.HMAC,n=j.PBKDF2=e.extend({cfg:e.extend({keySize:4,hasher:j.SHA1,iterations:1}),init:function(d){this.cfg=this.cfg.extend(d)},compute:function(e,b){for(var g=this.cfg,k=m.create(g.hasher,e),h=d.create(),j=d.create([1]),n=h.words,a=j.words,c=g.keySize,g=g.iterations;n.length<c;){var p=k.update(b).finalize(j);k.reset();for(var f=p.words,v=f.length,s=p,t=1;t<g;t++){s=k.finalize(s);k.reset();for(var x=s.words,r=0;r<v;r++)f[r]^=x[r]}h.concat(p);
a[0]++}h.sigBytes=4*c;return h}});g.PBKDF2=function(d,b,e){return n.create(e).compute(d,b)}})();
</script>

<script>
var salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("60c100d05c610e8b94a854dfc0789885");
var message = "Hello";
var key128Bits = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(message, salt, { keySize: 4, iterations: 1 });

// Logs "584519ef3e56714e301a4d85f972b6b4"
console.log(key128Bits.toString());
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nettle-pbkdf2 [documents](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/nettle-bin/nettle-pbkdf2.1.en.html) it uses HMAC-SHA256 as its pseudo-random function; the other two are using HMAC-SHA1. Nettle has a PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1 implementation, but I'm not sure if you can easily get it from the command line. (HMAC-SHA256 is generally a better choice if you have the option; SHA1 should be avoided).

(Of course, you also shouldn't be using 1 iteration. I presume that's just for testing.)

Comment: What source are you using? I found https://www.lysator.liu.se/~nisse/nettle/nettle.html which says "7.6.2 PBKDF2 -- 
The most well known PBKDF is the PKCS #5 PBKDF2 described in RFC 2898 which uses a pseudo-random function such as HMAC-SHA1." Presumably this is an older reference than what you found.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I am now getting consistent results by using SHA256: `CryptoJS.algo.SHA256`.

Comment: @JeffSchaller manpage for the CLI tool, e.g., https://manpages.debian.org/buster/nettle-bin/nettle-pbkdf2.1.en.html